# Solidity Smart Contract withdrawal ETH with amount from contract address does not work

Tags: solidity, truffle-contract, solidity-0.6.x

I have below smart contract and a test program to test transfer ETH out of contract address, but contract’s ETH balance not changed. I tested withdrawAmount(uint256 amount) but the assertion error occurred. I also use msg.sender.transfer(getBalance()); this work will transfer all balance out of contract, but I want to transfer with my amount with **withdrawAmount(uint256 amount)** function. How does msg.sender.transfer(amount) work in solidity0.6.10? How can I transfer the ETH’s amount from contract’s address?

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.1.26 (core: 5.1.26)
Solidity - 0.6.10 (solc-js)
Node v10.20.0
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

#ContractBalanceTest.sol

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
 
 contract ContractBalanceTest {
     address public owner;
 
     constructor() public payable {
         owner = msg.sender;
     }
 
     modifier onlyOwner () {
       require(msg.sender == owner, "This can only be called by the contract owner!");
       _;
     }
 
     function deposit() payable public {
     }
 
     function depositAmount(uint256 amount) payable public {
         require(msg.value == amount);
     }
 
 
     function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
         msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
     }
 
     function withdrawAmount(uint256 amount) onlyOwner payable public {
         require(msg.value == amount);
         require(amount <= getBalance());
         msg.sender.transfer(amount); //this not work
         //msg.sender.transfer(getBalance()); // this ok
     }
 
 
     function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
         return address(this).balance;
     }
 }
```

#test code

```
 var ContractBalance  = artifacts.require('ContractBalanceTest');
 
 contract('test contract balance with eth', function (accounts) {
   //console.log(accounts);
   let contract, balance;
   before(async function () {
     contract  = await ContractBalance.new({from: accounts[0]});
     balance   = await contract.getBalance();
     console.log('ContractBalanceTest ', contract.address, balance.toString());
     console.log('');
   });
 
   describe('#deposit', function () {
     it('test deposit', async function () {
       let one_eth = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
       let tx = await contract.depositAmount(one_eth, { from: accounts[1], value : one_eth});
       //console.log(tx);
       let b = await contract.getBalance();
       console.log('ContractBalanceTest ', contract.address, b.toString());
       assert.equal( b.toString(), "1000000000000000000", "the contract's balance should be 1 ether");
     });
   });
 
   describe('#withdraw', function () {
     it('test withdraw', async function () {
       let half_eth = web3.utils.toWei("0.5", "ether");
       let tx = await contract.withdrawAmount(half_eth, { from: accounts[3], value : half_eth});
       //let tx = await contract.withdraw({ from: accounts[0], value : half_eth});
       //console.log(tx.logs);
       let b = await contract.getBalance();
       console.log('ContractBalanceTest ', contract.address, b.toString());
       assert.equal( b.toString(), "500000000000000000", "the contract's balance should be 0.5 ether" );
     });
   });
 
 });
```

#test result

```
  Contract: test contract balance with eth
ContractBalanceTest  0xb7Ff5FB586177E7F489B956e7b218CdeB731B319 0

    #deposit
ContractBalanceTest  0xb7Ff5FB586177E7F489B956e7b218CdeB731B319 1000000000000000000
      ✓ test deposit (131ms)
    #withdraw
ContractBalanceTest  0xb7Ff5FB586177E7F489B956e7b218CdeB731B319 1000000000000000000
      1) test withdraw

    Events emitted during test:
    ---------------------------

    ContractBalanceTest.Transfer(
      amount: <indexed> 500000000000000000 (type: uint256)
    )


    ---------------------------


  1 passing (508ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: test contract balance with eth
       #withdraw
         test withdraw:

      the contract's balance should be 0.5 ether
      + expected - actual

      -1000000000000000000
      +500000000000000000
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test_contract_balance.js:34:14)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: The comments in function `withdrawAmount` depict an impossible scenario! Please check again and make sure what the function really reverts on.

Comment: @goodvibration I checked whether the transaction is reverted,  the transaction is ok and the hash created, no error catched in assertion test.I use msg.sender.transfer(getBalance()) the balance transfered out.

Comment: You have 4 lines in this function. The comments there suggest that the function completes successfully when executing only lines [1,2,4], and that the function reverts when executing only lines [1,2,3]. This depicts an impossible scenario!

Comment: And BTW, if `amount` is equal to `msg.value`, then it is definitely going to be <= `address(this).balance`, because `msg.value` is always <= `address(this).balance`. So line 2 in that function is obviously redundant.

Comment: @goodvibration If I understand correctly . require(msg.value == amount); // check the the transaction ETH value whether equal the function(code)'s parameter
 require(amount <= getBalance()); // this is check the contract's balance
so no redundant problem.

Comment: The contract balance will always include the amount that has just been transfered (which is the value of `msg.value`). So yes - this is a redundant piece of code.

Comment: Hence, if `msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance)` completes successfully, then so should `msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)`. Hence, the comments that you have provided in this function depict an impossible scenario!

Comment: For the same `msg.sender`, it is impossible for lines [1,2,4] to pass while lines [1,2,3] fail.

Comment: I test it, but address(this).balance is not equal to msg.value,please confirm it if I misunderstand.

Comment: I didn't say `address(this).balance == msg.value`, I said `address(this).balance >= msg.value`. Always!

Comment: @goodvibration I comment  all the require statement, try it again, it also show no changed in contract balance, change other amount also not work.

Comment: Commenting out all the `required` statements is wrong!

Comment: @goodvibration thanks, I figured out the problem which value received from msg.value because withdrawAmount is also payable, so contract’s balance not changed.

Answer (score 1):

remove payable keyword, and remove value from  test code

```
    //remove payable and msg.value
    function withdrawAmount(uint256 amount) public {
         require(amount <= getBalance());
         msg.sender.transfer(amount);
         emit Transfer(amount);
 
     }
     //remove value field
     let tx = await contract.withdrawAmount(half_eth, { from: accounts[1] });
```